# kendo datasource bringing up empty records

Tags: java, jsp, datasource, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to have my grid datasource to retrieve data from a URL as well as using transport-destroy and transport-update:

```
var dataSourceKGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/editinline/read",
            data: {
                productCat: $("#productCBox").value()
            }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "/editinline/destroy"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/editinline/update"
        },
        schema: {
            id: "productDS",
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: {editable: false},
                    name: {type: "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The grid:

```
<kendo:grid name="kGridProduct" pageable="true" sortable="true" scrollable="true" navigatable="true" height="300">
    <kendo:grid-editable mode="inline"/>
    <kendo:grid-columns>
        <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name" />
        <kendo:grid-column title="Id" field="id" />
        <kendo:grid-column title="&nbsp;" >
            <kendo:grid-column-command>
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="edit" />
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="destroy" />
            </kendo:grid-column-command>
        </kendo:grid-column>
    </kendo:grid-columns>
    <kendo:dataSource data="dataSourceKGrid" pageSize="5">            
    </kendo:dataSource>
</kendo:grid>
```

I have the controller class handling the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-inline/read", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<product> read(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return prodDAO.list(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productCat")));
    }
```

The problem is that the grid shows up empty with exactly 15 records and both buttons don't work. I can use hardcoded valuesfor `productCat` but it still brings up 15 records that are empty. I also have a doubt, the way I wrote it, if the user selects a different category on the ComboBox will the grid data refresh or do I need to force it?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what doesn't work? Does not display data, the browser reports a problem? The request does not arrive to the server? What does you browser display if you try to open the service URL?

Comment: The grid displays 15 empty records and when I open the service URL (http://localhost:8080/projectname/editinline/read) I get a null pointer exception that is not displayed on the server output